# Pyspark: Read multiple csv files and annotate them with the source

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark

We've been running into issues with bulk file ingestion into spark.

Currently, I'm aware that multiple file ingestion can be done with wildcards

```
spark.read.csv("path/to/file*.csv")
```

or via passing a list of paths of interest

```
spark.read.csv(["path/to/file1.csv", "path/to/file2.csv"])
```

In our situation, we have a large number of files (>100k) with file_name encoded IDs and no id encoded within the table itself. Using either method above acts like a simple union of the files, and doesn't seem to allow for the storage of the filename anywhere within the dataset.

How would I go about combining all these csvs while maintaining the filename encoded ID.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

there is a simple function called [`input_file_name`](https://spark.apache.org/docs/2.4.7/api/python/pyspark.sql.html#pyspark.sql.functions.input_file_name).

```py
from pyspark.sql import functions as F

df = spark.read.csv("path/to/file*.csv").withColumn("filename", F.input_file_name())
```